# DataGrid: Data Retrieval Issue

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In my WPF application,DataGrid is defined like below.

```
<my:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Height="212" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="28,339,0,0" 
    Name="dgChg" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="827"                       
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    GridLinesVisibility="All" 
    FontSize="12" 
    SelectionUnit="Cell" 
    CanUserAddRows="False" 
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
    CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
    CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
    CanUserSortColumns="False" 
    EnableRowVirtualization="True"  
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    TabIndex="9">
<my:DataGrid.Columns>                    
    <my:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check" Binding="{Binding Path = SELECT}"/> 
    <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CHG}" Visibility="Visible" Header="Chg Desc" IsReadOnly="True" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"/>  
    <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount}" PBOValidation:TextBoxMaskBehavior.Mask="Decimal" 
        Visibility="Visible" Header="Amount" IsReadOnly="False" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"/>
</my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

When ever I delete the existing value present in the Amount cell by entering back space and then check the Amount filed value in some button click event looks like cell is still in editing mode and I am not getting the latest value present in the cell. I am trying to get the value in button click like below.

```
DataTable dtCMICharges = ((DataView)dgChg.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

Even if I call `CancelEdit()` or `CommitEdit()` methods of DataGrid before above line is also no use.I am always getting old value before delete instead of latest one.

Please help me how to get the latest value of the cell.

Comment: If the Button is located outside of the DataGrid, the cell value should be committed when you click it anyway. So where and how is your Button defined?

Comment: Or, you can watch for keystrokes each time, a when ready end the cell editing to get committed changes to the grid.